# sqlite3: passing function argument as part of SQL statement

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Using the sqlite3 module from Python. Is there a way to pass a function argument into an SQL statement? Roughly something like the example code below:

```
def func(param):
    
    cur.execute("""
    SELECT * FROM this_table
    WHERE this_column_value = param
    """)
```

Comment: `cur.execute("""
    SELECT * FROM this_table
    WHERE this_column_value = (?)
    """, param)`

Comment: @Epsi95 Thanks, your code works nicely after changing `param` to `(param,)` but I can't accept a comment as an answer though

Comment: you can answer yourself and accept that to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cur.execute("""
SELECT * FROM this_table
WHERE this_column_value = (?)    
""", (param,))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cur.execute(f'SELECT * FROM this_table\
              WHERE this_column_value = {param}')
```